# Python display .png image to tkinter

Tags: python, image, opencv, user-interface, tkinter

I'm making a tkinter gui where I need to display an image. I have a gif file and a png. As far as I understand, tkinter is only supposed to support gif files and so those are working fine, however I also need to display my png image as well without using any online image converters. Does anyone know a way that I can display that png image to my gui, or atleast convert my png image to a gif file within the code itself?
All help is appreciated,
Thanks!

Comment: If you search it in other questions,maybe you will find `tkinter` also support `png` image.

Answer (score 0):

First google search and I see how to insert an image :

```py
def ouvrir():
    image = PhotoImage(file='YOURPNG.png')
    item = can1.create_image(300, 300, image = image)
    can1.image = image
    can1.pack()
```

Comment: But what is can1?

Comment: It's a canva I believe